# Multiple masters to single slave replication

Tags: database, centos, mariadb, replication, master-slave

I'm trying to set up replication from multiple clients servers with the same databases(MariaDB 10.3 on centos 7.0, same tables, different content) to a single host server.
What are the best practices to do this and what's the easiest way to accomplish that? 
Should I have multiple MySQL instances on my host machine?
or maybe if I have a database called

```
employees
```

on the clients, I should save 3 databases named

```
${hostname}employees
```

on my host machine?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replication-rewrite-db=old_name->new_name` to write changes to a certain database to a different database on the slave side:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-filters/#replicate_rewrite_db

This is also possible on a per-mater basis with multi source replication:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/multi-source-replication/#replicate-variables

See also this detailed description of such a multi source rewrite setup:

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/multisource-replication-how-to-resolve-the-schema-name-conflicts/